# make: g++: error: CreateProcess: No such file or directory

Tags: c++, makefile, cygwin, mingw

I see that this issue has been posted many many times but none of solutions worked for me and my problem is a bit different.

The problem:

When a use a makefile and mingw32-make, I get the error:

```
g++: error: CreateProcess: No such file or directory
```

However, if I copy/paste the SAME command that the makefile tried to do and paste it in the SAME command prompt it works. This problem only occurs when I try to build with a makefile.

Here's more info:

```
g++ ./src/main.cpp ./src/application.cpp -I C:\Code\infographie\Labs\inc -L    C:\Code\infographie\Labs\lib -I C:\Code\infographie\Labs\inc -g -Dmain=SDL_main -L C:\Code\infographie\Labs\lib -lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2 -o  bin/debug/labs.exe
g++: error: CreateProcess: No such file or directory
makefile:23: recipe for target 'all' failed
mingw32-make: *** [all] Error 1
```

As I said, If I copy/paste the first line it will work.

What can I try?

UPDATE: I've installed cygwin, adjusted SDL libs and recompiled. Now I get this error when I try to use make. If I copy/paste the command, it works.

```
g++ ./src/main.cpp ./src/application.cpp -I C:\Code\infographie\Labs\inc -L   C:\Code\infographie\Labs\lib -I C:\Code\infographie\Labs\inc -g -Dmain=SDL_main -L C:\Code\infographie\Labs\lib -lcygwin -lSDL2main -lSDL2 -  mwindows -o bin/debug/labs.exe
make: g++: Command not found
make: *** [makefile:23: all] Error 127
```

FIXED IT, don't declare a variable named PATH...

Comment: I'm no make guru, but I think you should make a MCVE makefile and see if that exposes the problem. If not, post the MCVE makefile and odds are good that someone who is a make guru will spot the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stop using MinGW.

MinGW has not been updated [since 2013](//sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/files). It has been replaced by Cygwin and
MSYS2. The MinGW project doesn’t even offer a [64-bit compiler](//sourceforge.net/p/mingw-w64/wiki2/History).

Cygwin can be installed in about [3 minutes](//serverfault.com/a/409076), I would give it a try.

Comment: Ok, I tried cywin and I get a similar issue. See my update above.

Comment: fixed it, I declared a variable named path and that must have overridden something. It's finally working now, thanks.